# getting error while implementing inbuilt database using sqlite in phonegap application

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

i am trying the idea of storing username and password of login time in a inbuilt database table, generated using sqlite.

Here is my code for that :-

```
//database //

//Transaction success callback
function createDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserInfo (username , password)'); 
}
function successCB() {
 var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Uinfo", 100000);
 db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

//Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
 console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}



//deleting previous record

function delDB(tx){
    tx.executeSql('DELETE * FROM UserInfo;')
}

//Query the database

function queryDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM UserInfo', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

//Query the success callback

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
 var len = results.rows.length;
 if (len != null){
 console.log("UserInfo table: " + len + " rows found.");
 for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
     console.log("Row = " + i + " UserName = " + results.rows.item(i).username + " Password =  " + results.rows.item(i).password);
     username = results.rows.item(i).username;
     password = results.rows.item(i).password;
     document.getElementById('uNameId').value = username;
    document.getElementById('pswd').value = password;
 }
}else{

}
}


//populating table

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO UserInfo (username, password) VALUES ('+'"'+userNameInput+'"'+', '+'"'+passwordInput+'"'+')');
}
```

After executing this code within ondeviready function, it works but throws an error in console like:-

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "*": syntax error
```

I was unable to find out the reason. Any help regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in delete query in delDB(tx) function how to use wrong syntax
Syntax:  DELETE FROM table_name [WHERE Clause]

```
function delDB(tx){    
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM UserInfo;')//change * remove in your function    
}
```